# How to pass int value from one class to another in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hai I am new to xcode My code is below,

```
 -(void)XYZ:(NSString *)id1 {
     int id2 = [id1 intValue];
     NSLog(@"%d",id2);
 }
```

I need to use the id2 value in another class like below,

```
-(NSArray *)Vehicles {
    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxxxx.com/xxx_webservice/vehiclelist.php?uid=%d&format=json",id2];
}
```

Please guide me to pass the value thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should read some docs about objective-c and OOP.

What you are calling classes, are methods. And if you want to pass one variable to a method, you have to declare it in the method declaration:

```
-(NSArray *)Vehicles:(NSInteger) id2 {
    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.tranzlogix.com/tranzlogix_webservice/vehiclelist.php?uid=%d&format=json",id2];
}
```

And you have to pass it when you call it, if you are calling the method from your class, a correct way will be: `[self Vehicles:id2]`

But i suggest you to read a lot before asking so basic questions.